# Manually add plugin from repository to target definition

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin with a manually configured target definition.
What I want is to add the `CDT` plugin from the `oxygen offline repository`(I downloaded a local copy of the repository).

I navigate to `<path_to_repo>/features` and if I want to add the feature `org.eclipse.cdt_9.4.3.201802261533.jar`to my target definition, I add this line:

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
    <unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
    <repository location="file:/<path_to_repo>/"/>
</location>
```

But at some point eclipse complains about a missing plugin(stored in `<path_to_repo>/plugins`) which I didn't add to the target defintion.

When I add a feature I have to add `.feature.group` to the name of the feature.
What should I add to the plugin name in order to be found by eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can the follow below steps to add custom feature into eclipse target definition

1. Go to Eclipse Preferences
2. Navigate to "Plugin Development"
3. Navigate to "Target Platform"
4. Double click on the "Running Platform(Active)"
5. Click on "Add..."
6. Select "Features"
7. Select the location of your CDT feature and click on Finish

[image]

However, there are other ways if you don't want mess-up the target definition file!

1. Update directly using repo http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.3/
2. Download the archive/zip file and update through Eclipse update manager
3. If you have custom modified jars, directly place it in the /dropins folder and restart the Eclipse

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the effort and for the detailed answer! However I can add a feature without a problem and I'd add it even manually, the real question is how to add a plugin ( not a feature).